# Angular two-way binding is transferring incomplete data due to ChangeDetectionStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to implement a functionality which will display the items in a list on the right side. The list gets populated based on the user selections. When the user selects an item from the hierarchy on the left, it is added to the list. I want to display the items on the right.

slice.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as API from '../../shared/api-routes';
import { BasestepComponent } from '../basestep-component/basestep.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import html from './slice.component.html';
import css from './slice.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'slice-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class SliceComponent extends BasestepComponent<string> implements OnInit {
  selections: string[] = [];
  newList: string[];

  constructor(dataService:DataService, cd:ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(dataService, cd);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  public onSliceChange(event:string):void {
    this.newList = [];
    this.selections.push(event);
    this.newList = this.selections;
    console.log(this.selections); //this has all the items selected
  }

}
```

slice.component.html:

```html
  <fortune-select
 (sliceSelected)="onSliceChange($event)">
  </fortune-select>
  <rightside-component
      [sliceNodes]="newList">
  </rightside-component>
```

rightside.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import html from './rightside.component.html';
import css from './rightside.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'rightside-component',
  template: html,
  providers: [DataService],
  styles: [css],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class RightSideComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() sliceNodes: string[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  getSlices() : string[] {
    if (typeof(this.sliceNodes) == "undefined" || (this.sliceNodes) === null) {
      return [];
    }
    return this.sliceNodes;
  }

}
```

rightside.component.html:

```html
<ul class="selection-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of sliceNodes">
      <button class="btn" >
        <i class="fa fa-close"> {{ item }} </i>
      </button> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the rightside component, only the first item which is selected is present and hence displayed on the right. I can see that all the items which have been selected are present in "this.newList" in slice.component.ts

However, the entire list is not getting transferred to the rightside component. sliceNodes is getting only the first item. I want all the items in the list to get transferred.

I am using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush hence it is not recognizing the changes which are not in @Input.

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Consider creating a StackBlitz if possible.

Comment: I tried to create one but it gives me errors. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuty1w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts . I am not sure how I can imitate my code here since "fortune-select" emits a string which is selected from the hierarchy every time.

Comment: Do you have a reason to want to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data source of the right side component to be a BehaviorSubject and then use the async pipe to consume it in the markup.  I've created a primitive [StackBlitz here](https://angular-xsak9c.stackblitz.io).

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

export class AppComponent  {
  list1 = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
  list2 = [];

  listSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);

  onItemClick(item: string){
  this.list2.push(item);
  this.listSubject.next(this.list2);
    }
}
```

When an item on the list is clicked, it is added to the list2 array. Then call next() method on the listSubject to notify subscribers to act.

Markup:

```
<label>Click item to select:</label>
<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <ul *ngFor="let item of list1" style="list-style: none;">
    <li (click)="onItemClick(item)">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<label>Selected items:</label>
<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <ul *ngFor="let item of listSubject | async" style="list-style: none;">
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The markup is using the "async" pipe to consume the list subject and will update whenever new changes are pushed.  I think this will get you going in the right direction.